# React parcel build faild

Tags: parcel

Command :- Npx parcel index.html

Error :- server running at
http://localhost:1234
Build faild.
Could not resolve module
"@parcel/transformer-js-win32-x64-msvc"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwEKG.png)

I am trying to update parcel then run the command but problem not solve.